# Javascript isNaN and null

Tags: javascript

In Javascript

`parseInt(null)` returns a `NaN`
`parseNumber(null)` also returns a `NaN`

`isNaN('abcd')` returns `true`, as 'abcd' is of course not a number,
`isNaN(5)` returns `false`

but strangely

`isNaN(null)` returns `false`, which is odd as implies it is a number, but as we saw in the `parseNumber` it was seen by that as `NaN`

There appears to be an inconsistency between the way null is viewed by `parseInt` and by `isNaN` one sees it as NaN and the other sees it as a Number. Why are they inconsistent?

Comment: what is `parseNumber` by the way?

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that happens in `isNaN()` is that the argument is coerced to a number. That is, it's as if the function looked like:

```
function isNaN(n) {
    n = +n;
    // ...
}
```

When `null` is coerced to a number, the value is `0`. That's not `NaN`.

The `isNaN` function really should not be used as a test to see if a value is a number; that's not what it's for. It's for testing to see if a *number* — that is, something you *know* is a number — is `NaN`.

In modern runtimes, there's `Number.isNaN()`, which does *not* perform that type coercion. Of course, with that, `null` is *still*
 not `NaN`.

Comment: And then the other part of this is that `parseInt` coerces the input to a string so that, in the end, both functions convert `null` to something else.

Comment: @DocMax right. Passing `null` to `parseFloat()` does return `NaN`, but I would still consider that to be a little fragile.

Comment: Oh, absolutely! The fact that it returns `NaN` is more a happy accident than it is the function doing what you would expect given the input.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for explaining why it returns the result. So really the use case for isNaN is rather specialised. The top result in google for testing if a variable is not a number was https://www.mkyong.com/javascript/check-if-variable-is-a-number-in-javascript/  and here they suggested using isNaN  so perhaps due to the naming of isNaN there appears to be some confusion.

Comment: @Pointy its good to know why its behaving this way. but the expectation created by its name, needs to match its behaviour. or else it kind of feels wrong. Perhaps the isNaN should not coerce a null to a 0 and should treat null as a special case

Comment: @MickeyPuri understand that the term `NaN` comes from the IEEE 754 floating point system. It's a set of bit patterns that are invalid, and therefore "not numbers".